Tester comparison
I need to compare the results from a set of different testers to find if there is a significant difference between them.
Each tester can either pass or reject an object. I have the data of each tester, and thus each % of rejection, and the data of the team as a whole.
The ideal aim should be to “train” my testers so a random object has the same probability of being rejected by any tester. So I need a reliable way to find if any testers have been too strict or too loose with the rejection criteria.
I've tried to use the standard deviation of the whole distribution and apply a 2-sigma interval center on the mean, but since the distribution is not normal (in fact is pretty flat) I think is not very representative…
Any ideas on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated
Clarifications:
——————————————-

The objects to be tested, while different are from a normal distribution and drawn randomly and in great numbers for each tester, so they can be considered as “the same” for all.
Although the pass/reject criteria can be determined objectively for each test we do not have that information for all the test. We want to know if any of the testers deviate from the others.
We do have the aggregate rejection rate for each tester AND the individualized data for each test (ie tester 1, has a set: pass/pass/reject/pass…)
Each object is tested only once.


Can you clarify something? Do you have the pass/reject value for each tester and each object, or do you have only the aggregate reject rate for each tester? In the latter case, I am afraid you will not be able to compare your testers (what if 2 testers have the exact same 5.00% reject rate, but they are rejecting completely different objects; a given object would have the "same probability" of being rejected (5.00%), but they would not be considered "equivalent", nor well trained. They need to reject "bad" objects at an equivalent rate, and "good" ones at an equivalent rate...

So, the object sample is basically randomized and follows a normal distribution. And I only have the aggregate for each tester, thus my problem.

Also, do you have the "ground truth", i.e. which object is really "bad" and which is really "good"? If you do not, your comparison may not have much value. Say that your testers all roll a die, and reject if they roll a 2 (snake eyes), and pass otherwise. They would all have almost identical pass/reject rates, and it would not mean anything...

There is a “ground truth” but I cannot access to it for all objects. But that is not the real problem since their distribution, in large numbers which each tester has, should be roughly equal for all testers…

And how can a discrete, nominal data (pass/reject) follow a normal distribution, which is continuous, numeric?

Basically, cause is actually a continuous parameter that is not important for the issue at hand so I simplify it hehe. And also there is not  just one parameter that is measured to obtain the pass/reject… We need to study only the difference, if any, between the testers accounting only their aggregate reject ratio.   Also there is a HUGE sample of objects for each tester so we can assume that it follows a normal distribution pretty close
